# Fast way to measure how many nodes are neighbors in a graph matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, data.table, apply

I have a `symmetric` `matrix` of distances between nodes:

```
set.seed(1)
dist.mat <- matrix(runif(10*10,0,1),10,10)
dist.mat[lower.tri(dist.mat)] <- t(dist.mat)[lower.tri(dist.mat)]
```

In reality this `matrix` is 40,000 by 40,000

For a given range of radii:

```
radii <- seq(0,1,0.01)
```

for each node I'd like to compute what fraction of the total number of nodes are located within that radius from it, and then average that over all nodes.

This is what I'm currently using but I'm looking for something faster.

```
sapply(radii,function(r)
  mean(apply(dist.mat,1,function(x) length(which(x <= r))/ncol(dist.mat)))
)
```

And here's its performance:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply(radii,function(r) mean(apply(dist.mat,1,function(x) length(which(x <= r))/ncol(dist.mat)))))
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                       expr     min
 sapply(radii, function(r) mean(apply(dist.mat, 1, function(x) length(which(x <=      r))/ncol(dist.mat)))) 2.24521
       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 2.548021 2.938049 2.748385 3.140852 7.233612   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using any *apply.

```
N <- 10
c(0, cumsum( table(cut(dist.mat, radii)) / (N*N) ))
```

`cut` it into the required intervals. 
Use `table` to tabulate frequencies. 
Then cumulative sum the result since anything smaller than prev radius is also smaller than the next large radius. Then average over all nodes.

The first 0 is because there is no value less than <= 0. (note that this might need to be improved on)

There is probably an even better solution using just the lower triangular matrix. Maybe someone will come along and provide an even faster solution.

---

EDIT: update with timings

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1L)
N <- 10e2
dist.mat <- matrix(runif(N*N,0,1),N,N)
dist.mat[lower.tri(dist.mat)] <- t(dist.mat)[lower.tri(dist.mat)]
radii <- seq(0,1,0.01)

f1 <- function() {
    sapply(radii,function(r)
        mean(apply(dist.mat,1,function(x) length(which(x <= r))/ncol(dist.mat)))
    )   
}

f2 <- function() {
    c(0, cumsum( table(cut(dist.mat, radii)) / (N*N) ))
}

microbenchmark(f1(),
    f2(),
    times=3L,
    unit="relative")

#Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f1() 8.580099 8.502072 8.501601 8.427282 8.464298 8.500692     3
# f2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000     3
```

Comment: `microbenchmark` indicates that this is slower than the `apply` approach

Comment: hi @dan, with 10x10 matrix of 40e3x40e3?

Comment: `> N <- 10
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(c(0, cumsum( table(cut(dist.mat, radii)) / (N*N) )))
Unit: microseconds
                                              expr    min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 c(0, cumsum(table(cut(dist.mat, radii))/(N * N))) 360.87 367.8135 415.0268 375.1595 419.365 1142.974   100`

Comment: how abt trying a size closer to your problem?

Comment: You're right. The `cumsum` approach becomes faster for larger `N`'s